# The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' context

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a console app to try out the C# 8 null reference types. Switched the project to build with lang ver C# 8.

Then the following code results in a warning.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string? message = "Hello World";
        string message2 = null;

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.WriteLine(message2);

        // The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' context
    }
}
```

What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 403, accepted):

For anyone ending up here.
You can put `#nullable enable` on top of the file for a file-by-file approach as suggested by @Marc in the comments.

You can also use combinations of #nullable enable/disable to annotate just parts of the file

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
#nullable enable
        string? message = "Hello World";
#nullable disable
        string message2 = null;

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.WriteLine(message2);
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts

> Nullable contexts enable fine-grained control for how the compiler interprets reference type variables. The *nullable annotation context* of any given source line is either enabled or disabled. You can think of the pre-C# 8.0 compiler as compiling all your code in a disabled nullable context: any reference type may be null. The *nullable warnings context* may also be enabled or disabled. The nullable warnings context specifies the warnings generated by the compiler using its flow analysis.
>
> The nullable annotation context and nullable warning context can be set for a project using the Nullable element in your `.csproj` file. This element configures how the compiler interprets the nullability of types and what warnings are generated. Valid settings are:
>
> - `enable`:
>
>   - The nullable annotation context is enabled. The nullable warning context is enabled.
>   - Variables of a reference type, `string` for example, are non-nullable. All nullability warnings are enabled.
> - `warnings`:
>
>   - The nullable annotation context is disabled. The nullable warning context is enabled.
>   - Variables of a reference type are oblivious. All nullability warnings are enabled.
> - `annotations`:
>
>   - The nullable annotation context is enabled. The nullable warning context is disabled.
>   - Variables of a reference type, `string` for example, are non-nullable. All nullability warnings are disabled.
> - `disable`:
>
>   - The nullable annotation context is disabled. The nullable warning context is disabled.
>   - Variables of a reference type are oblivious, just like earlier versions of C#. All nullability warnings are disabled.

In your `.csproj` file, simply add `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the relevant `<PropertyGroup>` element (your project file may have separate `<PropertyGroup>` elements for each project configuration name).

So your project file should look like this one:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

To display the nullable messages as errors instead of warnings, add this to your project file:

`<WarningsAsErrors>CS8600;CS8602;CS8603</WarningsAsErrors>`

...like so:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>CS8600;CS8602;CS8603</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The corresponding full messages are:

- CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
- CS8602: Possible dereference of a null reference.
- CS8603: Possible null reference return.

> You can also use directives to set these same contexts anywhere in your project:
>
> - `#nullable enable`: Sets the nullable annotation context and nullable warning context to enabled.
> - `#nullable disable`: Sets the nullable annotation context and nullable warning context to disabled.
> - `#nullable restore`: Restores the nullable annotation context and nullable warning context to the project settings.
> - `#nullable disable warnings`: Set the nullable warning context to disabled.
> - `#nullable enable warnings`: Set the nullable warning context to enabled.
> - `#nullable restore warnings`: Restores the nullable warning context to the project settings.
> - `#nullable disable annotations`: Set the nullable annotation context to disabled.
> - `#nullable enable annotations`: Set the nullable annotation context to enabled.
> - `#nullable restore annotations`: Restores the annotation warning context to the project settings.
>
> By default, nullable annotation and warning contexts are *disabled*. That means that your existing code compiles without changes and without generating any new warnings.

Note that pre-release versions of C# 8.0 and Visual Studio 2019 also supported `safeonly`, however [this option has since been removed](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13227) and is not present in the final shipping C# 8.0. Additionally the pre-release versions used `#pragma warning restore nullable` but the released version uses `#nullable restore warnings`.

Comment: Might also be worth expanding to cover `#nullable disable` and `#nullable restore` or a link to documentation covering all of them.

Comment: Answer edited to reflect the renaming of property `NullableContextOptions` to `Nullable` in VS 16.1.

Comment: Good answer. But for some reason approach with changing project parameters does not work for me. Using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Apparently the `safeonly` option is no-longer defined:  https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13227

Comment: I got Named attribute argument expected ERROR when using ```<Nullable>enable</Nullable>```

Comment: nice answer. I would add CS8618 to warnings as errors to cover: "Non-nullable property 'PbxUniqueCallId' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable."

Comment: I have this in my csproj so I shouldn't need to put anything extra in the code <Nullable>enable</Nullable> but I still get the error

Comment: The nullable directive can also now be defined for all projects in a directory using `Directory.Build.props`, see https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2021/07/14/directory-build-props-c-sharp-9-for-all/

Answer (score 37):

I got this same error too, and I spent a few days fighting it, for a reason not described by the other answers:  There are special (undocumented?) rules in the Roslyn C# compiler for *generated code* that uses the nullable feature, and until I upgraded Visual Studio 2019 to the latest version (16.4+), the error message was exactly the same unhelpful message as above — despite having `<Nullable>enabled</Nullable>` in my project file.

But in the latest versions of Visual Studio 2019, they've upgraded the error message to this:

> warning CS8669: The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a ‘#nullable’ annotations context. ***Auto-generated code requires an explicit ‘#nullable’ directive in source.***

(Emphasis added to the newly-added part of the error message.)

So if you're seeing this error message in any `.generated.cs` files you're emitting, those files need to have `#nullable enable` added to them *explicitly* — Roslyn apparently always ignores the project-level `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` setting for generated code.

Comment: The documentation for C#'s nullable contexts for generated files is under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts. They've added an "Important" subsection that lists the 4 ways a file is marked as generated.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and that's a good find!  It's good that they've finally added the documentation; but it's bad that it was a completely-undocumented "magic" rule for several years prior.

Comment: I also got the CS8632 warning even in a newly created .NET 6.0 project, own code, within an older solution that doesn't use the C#8 nullable reftypes. The new project has `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` set. Solution: delete all _bin_ and _obj_ directories in the solution, as also recommended for net6 migration by MS. "Clean Solution" was not sufficient in my case.

Comment: any idea why this is like this?

Comment: Users are often not in control of the code generators they use. Therefore enabling nullable in their project doesn't necessarily mean the generated code in their project is accurately nullable-annotated. We want the code generator itself to indicate that it has onboarded to nullable. Therefore we default the generated files to nullable-disabled, expecting that the generator will update to include `#nullable enable` when it onboards to nullable.

Comment: What a complete and utter mess

Comment: Agree with Richard Hammond, what a mess. Undoubtedly part of this is the price we pay for MS worshipping at the altar of backward compatibility. The link in the first comment says ? is "not allowed" with a reference type if I set Nullable to disabled, but it is both allowed and I get the warning. And this is in non-generated code.

Answer (score 8):

All reference types, like string or objects, are nullable by nature. It means that in  pre-C#8.0 we can just do like this: `string message = null`

In post-C#8.0 if option `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` or `#nullable enable` directive are set, reference types are treated like non-nullable by default. It means we have to explicitly indicate that they are nullable, like this: `string?`. As we did before for `int?`

That's it (more details in the popular answers).

Option name is a bit misleading because `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` is actually disabling default nullability behaviour of reference types, and visa versa. So, think `<Nullable>` as "explicit nullability"

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was setting the declaration of an object with a nullable `?` operator. That was unneeded in my case and simply removing it solved the issue.

Example

```
public class Foo() {}

public class Bar() {
    private Foo? foo;
}
```

can be changed to be just

```
public class Foo() {}

public class Bar() {
    private Foo foo;
}
```

Just note any checks for HasValue will need to be also changed to check it like this:

```
foo != null
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

You can solve `CS8669` like this inside a razor file:

```
@{#pragma warning disable CS8669}
<fluent-search @ref=Element
               value=@Value
               current-value="@BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue)"
               @onchange="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @oninput="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
    @ChildContent
</fluent-search>
@{#pragma warning restore CS8669}
```

This will **not** work:

```
@{#nullable enable}
<fluent-search @ref=Element
               value=@Value
               current-value="@BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue)"
               @onchange="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @oninput="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
    @ChildContent
</fluent-search>
@{#nullable disable}
```

**Original:**

I got the error CS8669:

> The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in
> code within a '#nullable' annotations context. Auto-generated code
> requires an explicit '#nullable' directive in source.

However I could not make it go away with `#nullable enable` or `#pragma warning disable CS8669` for the following Blazor component:

```
#nullable enable
@namespace Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI
@inherits FluentSearch

#pragma warning disable CS8669
<fluent-search @ref=Element
               value=@Value
               current-value="@BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue)"
               @onchange="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @oninput="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
    @ChildContent
</fluent-search>
#pragma warning restore CS8669
```

[image]

The only thing that worked was using "Exclude specific warnings as errors" in Project properties:

[image]

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningLevel>9999</WarningLevel>
    <WarningsNotAsErrors>0436;NU1608;CS8669</WarningsNotAsErrors>
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningLevel>9999</WarningLevel>
    <WarningsNotAsErrors>0436;NU1608;CS8669</WarningsNotAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this error at runtime when loading a cshtml page. It turns out we had runtime compilation on in our site. Disabling that fixed the error for us.

We had to remove this line in our Program.cs file.
`builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`