# Dereference of a possibly null reference despite checking that the value is not null in the Linq Where() call

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, nullable, osrm

I have prepared a simple [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/20yqVf), which calls [an OSRM map matching service URL](https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/10.757938,52.437444;10.764379,52.437314;10.770562,52.439067;10.773268,52.436633?overview=simplified&radiuses=50;50;50;50&generate_hints=false&skip_waypoints=true&gaps=ignore&annotations=nodes&geometries=geojson) and parses the JSON response.

My problem is, that there is a line producing the `warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference`:

```
if (osrmResponse?.code == "Ok" && osrmResponse.matchings != null)
{
    return osrmResponse.matchings
        .Where(matching => matching != null)
        .SelectMany(matching => matching.legs ?? Enumerable.Empty<Leg>())
        .Where(leg => leg != null && leg.annotation != null && leg.annotation.nodes != null)
        // How to fix dereference of a possibly null value in the next line?
        .SelectMany(leg => leg.annotation.nodes ?? Enumerable.Empty<long>())
        // eliminate duplicate node ids by converting to an ISet
        .ToHashSet()
        .ToList();
}
```

I do not understand, why does the compiler consider the `leg` or `leg.annotaion` to be null if I check for that in `.Where` call just before the problematic line?

Is the reason maybe the signature of the `.Where()` call and how to solve it then?

The complete test case is copied below:

```
namespace OsrmMapMatch
{
    public class OsrmResponse
    {
        public string? code { get; set; }
        public Matching[]? matchings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Matching
    {
        public Leg[]? legs { get; set; }
    }
    public class Leg
    {
        public Annotation? annotation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Annotation
    {
        public long[]? nodes { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        const string OsrmUri = "?overview=simplified&generate_hints=false&skip_waypoints=true&gaps=ignore&annotations=nodes&geometries=geojson&radiuses=";

        readonly static (double lng, double lat)[] Locations = 
        {
            (10.757938, 52.437444),
            (10.764379, 52.437314),
            (10.770562, 52.439067),
            (10.773268, 52.436633),
        };

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string HttpClientMapMatch = "HttpClientMapMatch";

            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddHttpClient(HttpClientMapMatch, httpClient =>
                {
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/");
                }).Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            IHttpClientFactory? httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            HttpClient? httpClient = httpClientFactory?.CreateClient(HttpClientMapMatch);
            if (httpClient == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error httpClient is null");
                return;
            }

            IEnumerable<long> nodes = await GetOsmNodesAsync(httpClient, Locations);
            Console.WriteLine($"Map matched OSM node ids: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(nodes.OrderBy(node => node))}\n");
        }

        private static async Task<IEnumerable<long>> GetOsmNodesAsync(HttpClient httpClient, IEnumerable<(double lng, double lat)> locations)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> lngLats = locations
                .Select(location => $"{location.lng:F6},{location.lat:F6}")
                .ToList();

            IEnumerable<int> radiuses = locations
                .Select(location => 50)
                .ToList();

            string requestUri = string.Join(";", lngLats) + OsrmUri + string.Join(";", radiuses);
            OsrmResponse? osrmResponse = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<OsrmResponse>(requestUri);
            if (osrmResponse?.code == "Ok" && osrmResponse.matchings != null)
            {
                return osrmResponse.matchings
                    .Where(matching => matching != null)
                    .SelectMany(matching => matching.legs ?? Enumerable.Empty<Leg>())
                    .Where(leg => leg != null && leg.annotation != null && leg.annotation.nodes != null)
                    // How to fix dereference of a possibly null value in the next line?
                    .SelectMany(leg => leg.annotation.nodes ?? Enumerable.Empty<long>())
                    // eliminate duplicate node ids by converting to an ISet
                    .ToHashSet()
                    .ToList();
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<long>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code executes without any issues, please specify how to see woringing or exception on null values

Comment: @PowerMouse: It's a compiler/linter warning, not a run-time exception.

Comment: also, is there a reason to use ISet for distinct rows? Enumerable.Distinct<T>() or .Distinct() should remove duplicates.. i try to copy your code to my local environment. it gives me different messages: CS8632. so warning can be suppressed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492214/the-annotation-for-nullable-reference-types-should-only-be-used-in-code-within-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current linters cannot analyze every possible execution path and so this linter is detecting a false positive possible null dereference.

Your RI (real intelligence) is superior in this case.

The language provides a mechanism, the [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving), to avoid this linter warning.

> Without the null-forgiving operator, the compiler generates the
> following warning for the preceding code: Warning CS8625: Cannot
> convert null literal to non-nullable reference type. By using the
> null-forgiving operator, you inform the compiler that passing null is
> expected and shouldn't be warned about.

Application here:

```
leg!.annotation!.nodes
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, the language rules know nothing about the relationship between the lambda condition passed to `Where` and the data passed to the lambda in `SelectMany`.  It only knows the data type of the lambda argument, and that data type is still `class Leg` which has an `Annotation?` member.

Even though all the null values have been removed/resolved, that fact isn't known to the compiler null checker.